# Generics "method does not override any method from its superclass"

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface, overriding

I have created an interface with a generic method, when overriding this method in my class that implements this interface the compiler complains saying "method does not override method from its superclass". This problem occur only when i added a generic param to my abstract method.

I created an interface whith one generic method and a Class that implements this interface.

```
package me.work.rest;
public interface RestControllerFacade<T> {
    <P, R, E extends Throwable> R retrieveCollectionResources(P p) throws E ;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/Users")
public class UserResource implements RestControllerFacade<User> {
    @GetMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> retrieveCollectionResources(Pageable 
    pageable) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        code...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The compiler says "method does not override method from its superclass". 
By the way this code is working for me :

```
package me.work.rest;
public interface RestControllerFacade<T> {
    <R, E extends Throwable> R retrieveCollectionResources() throws E ;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/Users")
public class UserResource implements RestControllerFacade<User> { 
@GetMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> retrieveCollectionResources() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        code...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Only when adding the P param to the method the compiler complains!
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to be a valid override, then `P`, `R`, and `E` need to be generics on the *interface*, not the method.  It has to be

```
public interface RestControllerFacade<P, R, E extends Exception, T> {
    R retrieveCollectionResources(P p) throws E ;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/Users")
public class UserResource implements 
        RestControllerFacade<
           Pageable, 
           ResponseEntity<Page<User>>, 
           ResourceNotFoundException, 
           User> {
    @GetMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> retrieveCollectionResources(Pageable 
    pageable) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        code...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The way you have written it, *any* `RestControllerFacade` has to be able to work for *any* `P`, `R`, and `E`, not just *some particular* combination.

Comment: Yes, i want to work for any P, R and E not just for some particular combination as you did in your answer by implementing "RestControllerFacade<
           Pageable, 
           ResponseEntity<Page<User>>, 
           ResourceNotFoundException, 
           User>"

Comment: Generic Methods:
You can write a single generic method declaration that can be called with arguments of different types. Based on the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, the compiler handles each method call appropriately. Following are the rules to define Generic Methods −
    1.All generic method declarations have a type parameter section delimited by angle brackets (< and >) that precedes the method's return type ( < E > in the next example).
    2.Each type parameter section contains one or more type parameters separated by commas.

Comment: A type parameter, also known as a type variable, is an identifier that specifies a generic type name.
3.The type parameters can be used to declare the return type and act as placeholders for the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, which are known as actual type arguments.
    4.A generic method's body is declared like that of any other method. Note that type parameters can represent only reference types, not primitive types (like int, double and char).  I Think i'm respecting all the rules right ?

Comment: @user3072470 if you want it to work for any P, R, and E, then why do you think your version of UserResource is a valid implementation?  The code you wrote only works for one particular P, R, and E.

Comment: I agree with you, let me explain more things : i have two overloaded methods in the same previous interface the 1st one take a Long param and the second take a String param. My question is how can i substitute the Long type and the String Type with a generic type in order to have one generic method ? the same question is valid for my previous example how can i substitute the Pageable and Collection<T> with a Generic P parameter.  `<R, E extends Throwable> R retrieveOneResource(Long id) throws E;
    <R, E extends Throwable> R retrieveOneResource(String username) throws E;`

Comment: You can either have them as separate overloads with fixed types, or you can have two different classes, one with `P` being `Long` and one with `P` being `String`.  There's really no third option.  But bluntly, you should be asking a new question instead of trying to cram these ideas into a comment.